# Mongoose not waiting for document to be delivered in callback

Tags: express, asynchronous, mongoose

in my expressjs project im doing several database calls which depend one on another. For the calls to the postgresql database im using pg-promise and for the mongoDB calls im using mongoose.
Everything is working fine besides that sometimes it happens, that the mongoose callback of findoneandupdate() does not wait until the document is transfered which causes the next function to miss data

log output of code running as expected

`5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b1
5bc5a2da466f37f300d983ba
5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b7
[ 5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b1,
  5bc5a2da466f37f300d983ba,
  5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b7 ]`

log output of code running when callback does not have the document queried for before the next database call is executed

`5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b1
5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b7
[ 5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b1, 5bc5a2da466f37f300d983b7 ]
5bc5a2da466f37f300d983ba`

This is a code snipped of the route where to problem happens. The logging commands are marked with ->

```
var questions = JSON.parse(req.headers.questions);
var client_jwt = req.headers.authorization;
var amcs_entry_list_array = [];



database.db.one('SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT username FROM users WHERE $1 = ANY(tokens) ) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END', client_jwt)
.then(function (data) {

    if(data.case) {
        questions.forEach(function(question_id, idx, questionsArray) {
            var question_id = question_id.questionID; 

            database.db.multi('select * from questions where id = $1;select * from choices where question_id = $1', question_id)
            .then(function (data) {

                mongoose_models_amcs_entry.amcs_entry.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {amcs_request: {question_id: question_id,request_jwt: client_jwt}},          
                    {amcs_request: {question_id: question_id,request_jwt: client_jwt},amcs_response:{ question_data: data[0], choices_data: data[1]}}, 
                    {upsert:true,new:true}, 
                    function(err, doc){
                    if (err) return handleError(err);
                    amcs_entry_list_array.push(doc._id);
                 ->   console.log(doc.id);
                    if (idx === questionsArray.length - 1){ //if last response arrived
                     ->   console.log(amcs_entry_list_array);
                        mongoose_models_amcs_entry_list.amcs_entry_list.findOneAndUpdate(
                            {amcs_entry_list: {document_ids: amcs_entry_list_array}},          
                            {amcs_entry_list: {document_ids: amcs_entry_list_array}},         
                            {upsert:true,new:true}, 
                            function(err, doc){
                            if (err) return handleError(err);
                            res.send("http://localhost:8080/entry/"+doc._id);
                        });

                    }
                });


            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("ERROR:", error);
            });


        });

    }
```

How can I force the callback to wait until 'doc' is delivered before executing the callback after the marked console.log() commands?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using es2016. By this your code will wait for the result and will not jump to next instruction. You can visit here to learn more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

For reference your code will be like this.

```
database.db.one('SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT username FROM users WHERE $1 = ANY(tokens) ) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END', client_jwt)
.then(function (data) {

if(data.case) {
        questions.forEach(async function(question_id, idx, questionsArray) {
         var question_id = question_id.questionID; 
     var data = await database.db.multi('select * from questions where id = $1;select * from choices where question_id = $1', question_id)

    var output = await mongoose_models_amcs_entry.amcs_entry.findOneAndUpdate(
                                {amcs_request: {question_id: question_id,request_jwt: client_jwt}},          
                                {amcs_request: {question_id: question_id,request_jwt: client_jwt},amcs_response:{ question_data: data[0], choices_data: data[1]}}, 
                                {upsert:true,new:true})
     if (!optput._id) return handleError(err);
                amcs_entry_list_array.push(doc._id);
     console.log(doc.id);
     if (idx === questionsArray.length - 1){ //if last response arrived
           console.log(amcs_entry_list_array);
 var out1 = await mongoose_models_amcs_entry_list.amcs_entry_list.findOneAndUpdate(
                                            {amcs_entry_list: {document_ids: amcs_entry_list_array}},          
                                            {amcs_entry_list: {document_ids: amcs_entry_list_array}},         
                                            {upsert:true,new:true}) 
    if (!out1._id) return handleError(err);
    res.send("http://localhost:8080/entry/"+doc._id);
                    }
                    });
        }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("ERROR:", error);
        });
```

Comment: unfortunatly this doesnt help. when I alter the code in your provided way and make the surrounding function "async" I dont get any responses from mongoose at all. thanks for the answer

Comment: @I. Shm dont forget "await" and are you getting any error now ?

Comment: @I.Shm i miss the await before mongoose query please add that (Look at the ans again i just edit that)

Comment: seems that you removed .then( function (data) {, was this on purpose? When i alter the code it doesnt work :(

Comment: @I.Shm yes when we use await then we do not need .then(function(data)){} as  `var data = await query()` is same to `query().then()`

Comment: with some small changes the code runs, but with the same behaviour as before. https://pastebin.com/1V9drDnk       i get the same logging output as mentioned in the question... any ideas?